# SQLite как в методе query менять selectionArgs по нажатию на ListView в соседнем активити

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть `ListView` в `YearActivity` - список месяцев, по нажатию на который в другом активити `ListMonth` хочу отобразить список только данных из того месяца, на который был сделан выбор:

```
lvYear.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(YearActivity.this, ListMonth.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

ListMonth:

```
public class ListMonth extends AppCompatActivity  implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 

...

    private static class MySimpleCursor extends CursorLoader {

        DB db;

        public MySimpleCursor(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {

            Cursor cursor = db.getData();
            return cursor;
        }
    }
```

Есть база данных. В ней метод, где хочу сделать сортировку данных по месяцам:

```
public Cursor getData() {

    selectionArgs = new String[]{"11"};
    selection = "month = ?";
    orderBy = "day";
    return sqLiteDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
}
```

Как в `selectionArgs` передать, на какую позицию пользователь нажал?

`selectionArgs = new String[]{"11"}` - вот так к примеру отображается только ноябрь.

Answer (score 2):

В `YourActivity` у вас есть переход на активность `ListMonth`. Вам необходимо в `Intent` ложить число месяца. Например, для ноября

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YearActivity.this, ListMonth.class);
intent.putExtra("month",11);
startActivity(intent);
```

А в методе `onCreate()` активности `ListMonth` получать это число, переводить в `String` и использовать в методе `query()`:

```
String month = "" + getIntent().getIntExtra("month", 1);
...
selectionArgs = new String[]{month};
...
```

**Теперь к задаче**

У вас список из 12 месяцев? Они идут по порядку? Если да, то вам нужно отправлять `position+1`. Прибавление единицы нужно, так как индекс меньше позиции на единицу.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YearActivity.this, ListMonth.class);
intent.putExtra("month" ,position+1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Ну и во второй активности делай так, как я написал выше

Comment: Спасибо за поправку

Comment: Сергей Грушин Вам спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не могу передать Intent в класс DB и создать в нем метод onCreate.

Comment: @Bombey77 почему?